# Equations for displacement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, displacement

I have a pendulum which is manually operated and so does not slow down. It is going at a frequency of 10Hz. It has a maximum angle of 25 degrees and length 10 cm. What are the equations of displacement that I can use?

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia article on the [pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum)?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "manually operated" means? 10 Hz is ten times per second, which is awfully fast for a pendulum.

Comment: See Wikipedia "Pendulum mathematics" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)